# JSON Javascript doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, java, json, rest, jersey

I started developing a webinterface with bootstrap and so I used javascript to receive some JSON-Data.
My JSON-String is build with JSONObjects in JAVA and I used Jersey RestFUL-Service.

Java Code:

```
@GET
@Path("test")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String createTestJson(){

    JSONObject jsobject= new JSONObject();

    try {
        jsobject.append("test1", "test");
        jsobject.append("test2", "test");
        jsobject.append("test3", "test");
        jsobject.append("test4", "test");
        jsobject.append("test5", "test");
        jsobject.append("test6", "test");
        jsobject.append("test7", "test");

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jsobject.toString();

}
```

When I call the URL with the browser it works:

```
{"test1":["test"],"test2":["test"],"test3":["test"],"test4":["test"],"test5":["test"],"test6":["test"],"test7":["test"]}
```

I created a JavaScript function, which should retrieve the JSON String and fill the certain values in my HTML-page.

```
function loadJSON()
{
   var data_file = "http://127.0.0.1:8085/Rest/test/test";
   var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   try{
      // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari
      http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();

   }catch (e){
      // Internet Explorer Browsers
      try{
         http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      }catch (e) {
         try{
            http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
         }
      }
   }

   http_request.onreadystatechange  = function(){
      if (http_request.readyState == 4  )
      {

        alert(http_request.responseText.length);
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);

        document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML =  jsonObj.test1;
        document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML = jsonObj.test2;
      }
   }
   http_request.open("GET", data_file, true);
   http_request.send();
}
```

When I analyse the document with firebug, I can see that the GET- inquiry is completed and it's state is "200 OK". The answer of the inquiry is the JSON String.

I also analysed the script and it seems to stop working at:

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);
```

Additionally I wrote out the length of the responseText and the result is "0".

So I really don't get the problem. According firebug the script gets the data, but it breaks down at parsing the JSON String. It could relate to the responseText, which has a length of 0.

-------Edit-----

More Firebug information:

1. The XMLHTTPRequest-Object Data after receiving the data:

`DONE 4 
HEADERS_RECEIVED 2

LOADING 3

OPENED 1
UNSENT 0
mozAnon false

mozBackgroundRequest false
mozSystem false 
onloadend null
ontimeout null
readyState 1

response "" 
responseText "" 
responseType ""
responseXML null 
status 0

statusText ""

timeout 0`

2. The inquiry-header
   `Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
   Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
   Accept-Language de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
   Connection  keep-alive
   Host    127.0.0.1:8085
   Origin  null
   User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0`
3. The response-header
   `Content-Type   application/xhtml+xml
   Date    Mon, 24 Aug 2015 22:56:18 GMT
   Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
   Transfer-Encoding   chunked`

Response: 
`{"test1":["test"],"test2":["test"],"test3":["test"],"test4":["test"],"test5":["test"],"test6":["test"],"test7":["test"]}`

Maybe you can help me!

Thank you!

Marko

Comment: The string is length 0 and you are blaming the function for not parsing it?

Comment: But why is the String 0 ?

Comment: @Hacketo I know that jQuery.parseJSON  return object ,but by this you can achieve what ever you want from Json. May be I am wrong , but this is as per my knowledge.

Comment: @Hacketo I am removing my comment if i am wrong.

Comment: start by wrapping JSON.parse in a try catch.
That should tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that the responsetext is an empty string and I really don't know why?

Comment: I'd recommend displaying the whole `http_request` object on the browser's console so that you inspect the entire object in order to have a better idea of what's actually being returned: `console.log(http_request)`

Comment: @Markoo91 your could add a breakpoint and see where is stored your JSON in `http_request ` object.

Comment: Yes I did it and it's an empty String?!

Comment: `DONE 4   HEADERS_RECEIVED 2    LOADING 3   OPENED 1   UNSENT 0    mozAnon false    mozBackgroundRequest false    mozSystem false   onloadend null    ontimeout null    readyState 4 response ""    responseText ""    responseType ""    responseXML null status 0    statusText ""     timeout 0`

Comment: This is what the XMLHTTPRequest- Object contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be interested if your JSON is recieved as `type="application/json` or perhaps as XML/HTML. Could it be that the response is XML and so the "object" is stored inside `http_request.XML`?

---------- EDIT ----------

I think you are having issues with the [Same-Origin-Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) of JS. You cannot load your field because of that. Try to implement your JS inside a view of your Java-App (so that you can access it via http:// and in the same domain as your app) and try it again.

Comment: @Hacketo black magic, removed it.

Thought about implicit conversion to [literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals), my mistake

Comment: `DONE
 4
 
HEADERS_RECEIVED
 2
 
LOADING
 3
 
OPENED
 1
 
UNSENT
 0
 
mozAnon
 false
 
mozBackgroundRequest
 false
 
mozSystem
 false
 
onloadend
 null
 
ontimeout
 null
 
readyState
 4
 
response
 ""
 
responseText
 ""
 
responseType
 ""
 
responseXML
 null
 
status
 0
 
statusText
 ""
 
timeout
 0`

Comment: This is what the XMLHTTPRequest- Object contains. So the responseXML is null and the responseText is an empty String. So I don't get it?

Comment: Yeah, that's weird. When you look at the request at the debugger's "network" tab, what's the response?

Comment: Response-Header
`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 24 Aug 2015 14:06:14 GMT`

-------------------------------------

Inquiry-Header
`GET /Rest/test/testHTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8085
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: null
Connection: keep-alive`

Comment: The response seems fine to me. But the request does not allow `application/json` as response. He only allows `Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,/;q=0.8`. So perhaps it drops the response because of that.

Comment: Ok it made sense and I changed the mediatyp of my json application to text/html, but it still occurs the same problem. The responsetext or repsonsexml is an empty string. I really don't know what to do? Is there something wrong in my rest-application?

Comment: The Rest-app seems fine for me. I would return your java to `application/json` and add `http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");` to your JS. Do you get any errors or warnings in the console? Do you call your script from a `file://` path or is it part of your Rest-App?

Comment: Yes I did it, but nothing changes. There is still the empty String?! Is it an general problem of javascript? Is there another approach to solve my problem, because I need this f***ing JSON String for my webapplication. Yes I opened my HTML-File with a `file://`. Do you have any idea what I could try next?

Comment: I think you are having issues with the [Same -Origin-Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) of JS. You cannot load your field because of that. Try to implement your JS inside a view of your Java-App (so that you can access it via `http://` and in the same domain as your app) and try it again.

Comment: Yes thank you Wachiwi!! This was the problem! I added the cors in my header of the Rest-Response. So the porblem was solved!

 `return Response.ok() 
 .entity(s) // s= my Response-String
 .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
 .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT")
 .build(); `
  
  
  

 }`